# Trigger after browser painting / rendering

Tags: javascript, html, browser, vue.js

I'm using VUEJS to load and display a table tag on the screen.
This table is quite huge: around 1000 rows and 10 columns and might have to grow in the future (for the future we might have to deal with 8000 records)

Because of some UX requirements we need to have each cell width of the table header to be calculated based on table body size.
Basically we use 2 tables, one for the header, one for the body (so we can keep the header on top while scrolling down on the table), and thus each cell width has to be calculated based on each other.

```
if (headercell.width() > bodycell.width()) bodycell.width(headercell.width)
else header.width(bodycell.width)
```

This works fine, only issue is that the cell width is only available when the entire rendering/painting (not sure about the right term) is finished.
With a big table like this, I have to work with a timer which is not clean.

Any idea how I could catch when the rendering/painting process is finished so I can call that function?

Thanks

Comment: is `mounted` lifecycle event for Vue component not suitable in this case? If you have some child components so you can create `mounted` method and put your logic in `this.$nextTick` function to be sure that all child components rendered as well.

Comment: I'll give it a try but I think that it doesn't take the browser "painting" job into consideration. When the dom is created, my understanding is that it still has to be painted by the browser and this in my case takes some time.